# What is the CUDA Math Library equivalent for arg()?

Tags: math, cuda, complex-numbers

The C++ standard library has a function called [`std::arg()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/cpp_complex_arg.htm). It returns the phase angle (or angular component) of its complex number argument, expressed in radians.

I need to call something like `std::arg()` in a CUDA kernel.  Is there an equivalent function in the CUDA Math library, or CUDA Complex Math library?

Comment: I looked at `cuComplex.h` and it does not exit. CUDA only has rudimentary support for complex numbers; basically what is required by CUBLAS and CUFFT. You can easily compute the function yourself as arg (x + *i* y) = atan2 (y, x). CUDA supports the C++ standard math function `atan2()`.

Comment: Yes.  I just did something like this and it worked:             double myPhaseAngle = atan2(cuCimag(myComplexDouble), cuCreal(myComplexDouble));

Comment: https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__complex__numbers_gaaf1fe0eb083839813e90a6f7cb6d7585.html  Yes, that is [usable in an ordinary CUDA kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473826/cuda-how-to-work-with-complex-numbers/17474278#17474278), it does not require extensive use of other thrust constructs.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize and expand slightly on the comments:

- The CUDA math library offers no direct support of an `arg()` function for complex values.
- `cuComplex.h` is very rudimentary. As @njuffa notes: It only has what's required by CUBLAS and CUFFT.
- You can, and should, use `atan2(y, x)` (or `std::atan2(y, x)`), where `y` is the imaginary component and `x` is the real one.

Now, what about Thrust? `thrust::complex<T>` does have an `arg()` method, after all?

Well, this is how it's implemented:

```
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__
T arg(const complex<T>& z)
{
  // Find `atan2` by ADL.
  using std::atan2;
  return atan2(z.imag(), z.real());
}
```

(see also [on GitHub](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/b59d1db95e47f616cbf583b01a0a858a8f7c382f/thrust/detail/complex/arithmetic.h).) ... so, `atan2()` there as well.